# Can we have 2 different spring kafka consumer properties in a single application properties file?

Tags: spring-kafka

### Consumer1 Configuration details (for batch)

```
spring.kafka.consumer.[0].bootstrap-servers = ${bootstrap.servers1}
spring.kafka.consumer.[0].enable-auto-commit = false
spring.kafka.consumer.[0].auto-offset-reset = latest
spring.kafka.consumer.[0].max-poll-records = 100
spring.kafka.consumer.[0].key-deserializer= org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
spring.kafka.consumer.[0].value-deserializer= org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
spring.kafka.consumer.[0].properties.allow.auto.create.topics = false
spring.kafka.consumer.[0].properties.max.poll.interval.ms = 300000
spring.kafka.listener.[0].ack-mode = MANUAL
spring.kafka.listener.[0].concurrency = 1
```

### Consumer2 Configuration details (for single record)

```
spring.kafka.consumer.[1].bootstrap-servers = ${bootstrap.servers2}
spring.kafka.consumer.[1].enable-auto-commit = false
spring.kafka.consumer.[1].auto-offset-reset = latest
spring.kafka.consumer.[1].key-deserializer= org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
spring.kafka.consumer.[1].value-deserializer= org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
spring.kafka.consumer.[1].properties.allow.auto.create.topics = false
spring.kafka.consumer.[1].properties.max.poll.interval.ms = 300000
spring.kafka.listener.[1].ack-mode = MANUAL
spring.kafka.listener.[1].concurrency = 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No; to configure multiple sets of infrastructure, you need to define the beans manually instead of using auto configuration.

However, you can override individual properties on the `@KafkaListener` directly:

```java
    /**
     * Kafka consumer properties; they will supersede any properties with the same name
     * defined in the consumer factory (if the consumer factory supports property overrides).
     * <p>
     * <b>Supported Syntax</b>
     * <p>The supported syntax for key-value pairs is the same as the
     * syntax defined for entries in a Java
     * {@linkplain java.util.Properties#load(java.io.Reader) properties file}:
     * <ul>
     * <li>{@code key=value}</li>
     * <li>{@code key:value}</li>
     * <li>{@code key value}</li>
     * </ul>
     * {@code group.id} and {@code client.id} are ignored.
     * @return the properties.
     * @since 2.2.4
     * @see org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerConfig
     * @see #groupId()
     * @see #clientIdPrefix()
     */
    String[] properties() default {};
```

e.g. `@KafakListener( ..., properties = "bootstrap.servers=${bootstrap.servers2}")`

Comment: if I need to have different 'listener' properties for different listeners, is the only way to do it is to initialize different factory beans for each listener and pass them to annotation? I see from the 3.1 version that containerPostProcessor is available, I guess it could help, but I am on 2.7 version